# Asp.net MVC Application redirects to Login when attempting to append to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am experiencing the strangest behavior.  I am pretty sure the problem is with our application, but I cannot figure out how to track down the issue.  Whenever I try to use jQuery "append" to append something to a div in the view, the application appends the text and then abruptly redirects me to the login page for the app. I was, at first trying to append to a div so that I could dynamically add an item to a collection.  In trying to troubleshoot the behavior, I found that it doesn't matter what I try to append, it appends and then redirects to the login page.  Chrome Dev Tools does not show any errors so I am wondering if there is any other way to find out what is causing the redirect to the login page.  I have this button:

```
<a id="addAnother" href="#" onclick="addNew();">Add another</a>
```

calling this function:

```
    function addNew() {
    $('#testDiv').append('<div>Hello</div>');
}
```

When clicked, the button appends "Hello" to view and then redirects to login page.  Since there are no errors showing in Dev Tools, can anyone suggest how I can chase down what is happening?  I am new to both MVC and jQuery.

Comment: try with return false `onclick="addNew();return false;"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   
$('a#addAnother').on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
 e.stopImmediatePropagation();
 $('#testDiv').append('<div>Hello</div>');
return false;
})
</script>
```

In your variant the function is executed immediately and no event argument is being passed to it and  if you dont use preventDefault the click event goes up of DOM runnig at all parents elemens.